# Java to xml Serialization: How can i get fields name as a tag?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

MySql query:

```
select 'customers'  tableName , customers.* from customers
```

This is the serialization function:

```
        List<?> received = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
        FileOutputStream fich   = new FileOutputStream("xmlop.xml");
            XMLEncoder x = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(fich));
            x.writeObject(received);
            x.flush();
            x.close();
```

The result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_45" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <void method="add">
   <object class="org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap">
    <void method="put">
     <string>tableName</string>
     <string>customers</string>
    </void>
    <void method="put">
     <string>id</string>
     <int>1</int>
    </void>
    <void method="put">
     <string>firstname</string>
     <string>zied</string>
    </void>
    <void method="put">
     <string>lastname</string>
     <string>saffar</string>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
  <void method="add">
   <object class="org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap">
    <void method="put">
     <string>tableName</string>
     <string>customers</string>
    </void>
    <void method="put">
     <string>id</string>
     <int>2</int>
    </void>
    <void method="put">
     <string>firstname</string>
     <string>mohamed</string>
    </void>
    <void method="put">
     <string>lastname</string>
     <string>houidi</string>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

What shall i do to have something like this :

```
<customer>
    <id>1</id>
    <firstname>zied</firstname>
    <lastname>saffar</lastname>
</customer>
<customer>
    <id>1</id>
    <firstname>zied</firstname>
    <lastname>saffar</lastname>
</customer>
```

=> name field as a tag <==

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use JAXB to make that. Also you'd need to create a special class.

Check here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: In my case i dont have a class to use with jaxb, i have a List as an sql query result